# Why doesn't this Jekyll Liquid where filter filter?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am trying to output a list of blog posts for a certain author. I tried this where Jekyll filter:

```
{% for post in (site.posts | where:"author", "mike") %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it outputs every post. I'm not clear what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supposing that your post author is in your front matter, like this :

```
---
author: toto
...
---
```

If you want two last post by author == toto, just do :

```
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% assign maxPostCount = 2 %}
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.author == 'toto' and counter < maxPostCount %}
    {% assign counter=counter | plus:1 %}
    <li>{{ counter }} - {{ post.title }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Et hop !

**EDIT :**
And another solution using the where filter instead of the if clause :

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where: "author", "toto" %}
{% assign counter2 = 0 %}
{% assign maxPostCount2 = 3 %}
<ul>
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if counter2 < maxPostCount2 %}
    {% assign counter2=counter2 | plus:1 %}
    <li>{{ counter2 }} - {{ post.title }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

RE-EDIT: Justin is right I don't need my two vars (counter2 and maxPostCount2), I can use [Liquid for loop](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#for) **limit:n** option.

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where: "author", "toto" %}
<ul>
{% for post in posts limit:3 %}
  <Ol>{{ post.title }}</ol>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Better !

Comment: For the example of the where filter you don't need the counter logic and you can remove it completely if you don't want to number the list (which you could do with an OL tag anyway).

Comment: The counter logic is here to limit the number of returned results.

Comment: Edited my aswer to take Justin comment into account.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do an `assign` first for the filtered items

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where:"author", "mike" %}
{% for post in posts %}  
   {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems filters are to be used only inside output tags (those surrounded by `{{` and `}}`. Which mean you could use something like :

```
{{ site.posts | where "author", "mike" }}
```

But you can't use it the way you're doing.

*Source: [liquid documentation on Filters](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters)*

Comment: can you do it like this:
http://www.leveluplunch.com/blog/2014/04/03/sort-pages-by-title-filter-array-by-layout-jekyllrb/ i.e

`{% assign posts =  (site.posts | where "author", "mike") %}`?