# how in jekyll, for categories.html write a logic for posts in specific category using pagination?

Tags: html, loops, pagination, jekyll, liquid

I have posts with post.thumb and without post.thumb, and i want to show only posts with post.thumb in structure below without using limit and offset for posts.

I have a categories.html with next structure:

```
       <section class="type-one">
               {% for post in pagination.posts limit:1 Offset:0 %}              
                <div class="col-md-7">                        
                    {% include FirstPostInCategoryNews.html %}                        
                </div>
               {% endfor %}

                <div class="col-md-5 two_items_incide">
                    {% for post in pagination.posts limit:2 Offset:1 %}
                    {% include TwoPostsAfterFirstPostInCatNews.html%}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

        </section>

        <section class="others_posts_in_cat_news">              
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    {% for post in pagination.posts limit:7 Offset:3 %}
                    {% include OtherPostsInCategoryNews.html %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>                      
        </section>
```

for better understanding what i want is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951502/how-to-ignore-offset-in-jekyll-when-previous-post-is-skipped/52955001?noredirect=1#comment92854598_52955001)

Comment: I think you need a 'where' filter on your posts, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24701557/2397550

Comment: how can i write correct filter for {% for post in paginator.posts | where: "thumb", "starts with images/news...." %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution that works, with help of [JoostS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397550/joosts)

first of all I added to all my posts wich has post.thumb next tag (bg)

```
---
layout: post
thumb: "path/to/image/"
bg: "yes"
---
```

the next step is that I loop through all my posts with bg: "yes", by using filters.

so finaly here what i did:

```
<section class="type-one">
    <div class="row">

      {% assign posts = paginator.posts | where: "bg", "yes" %} // creating var//
      <div class="col-md-7"> 
      {% for post in posts limit: 1 %}
          {% include FirstPostInCategoryNews.html %}
      {% endfor %}
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5 item-title-white">
          {% for post in posts limit: 2 offset: 1 %}
              {% include TwoPostsAfterFirstPostInCatNews.html %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

2nd part:

```
<section class="others_posts_in_cat_news">              
            <div class="col-md-7">
                {% assign posts = paginator.posts | where: "bg", "yes" %}
                {% for post in posts limit: 4 offset: 3 %}
                {% include OtherPostsInCategoryNews.html %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>                      
 </section>
```

if sombody didnt understand something, feel free to ask!